# How to install libxul-embedding?

Tags: mozilla

So, like I said in the title, I need to use mozembed, the NewAPI to integrate GTK and Gecko. But, when I'm trying `./configure` it search for `libxul-embedding`, and I have no idea when I can find this lib.

Anyone knows, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

for that I think you need following commands. For adding repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa 

sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0-gnome-support 
sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0 
sudo apt-get install xulrunner-2.0-mozjs
sudo apt-get install libxul-dev
```

It's obvious that you will have to face some certain issues because it contains [bugs for workarounds](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Embedding/NewApi).

Comment: @Braiam It doesn't work for me. Still getting same error saying that package doesn't exist. Did you have another suggestion?! Thanks!

Comment: @Todi I'm not the answerer. Just someone that edited the answer.

Comment: Todi i was trying to get it done , but cudnt so on my request @braim suggest something that wud definitely work. even i wanted to know .. what xactly the problem is..

Comment: Sorry Braiam, I did not seen! @Sushantp606 and what he did?